# If $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\in(0,1]\;\;\forall x\in[0,1]$ then $\dfrac{\left(\int_0^1f'(x)dx\right)^2}{\int_0^1(f(x))^3}$ can not take values

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> If $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\in(0,1]\;\;\forall x\in[0,1]\;$ then $\dfrac{\left(\int_0^1f'(x)dx\right)^2}{\int_0^1(f(x))^3}$ can not take values
>
> - A) $\dfrac12$
> - B) $2$
> - C) $\dfrac14$
> - D) $1$

Numerator can be written as $f^2(1)=\int_0^1f^2(1)dx$

Also, for $x\in(0,1), f'(x)>0\implies f(x)$ is increasing. So, we can say $\int_0^1f^2(1)dx>\int_0^1f^2(x)dx$

But don't know how to compare it to $f^3(x)$.

Can we say $\int_0^1f^2(1)dx>\int_0^1f^3(x)dx$?

Can we use Cauchy Schwarz inequality here? Not able to figure out how.

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $f'\in(0,1]$ imply that $f$ takes on values...? Then what do you conclude about $f^2$ vs $f^3$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I conclude that $f$ is greater than zero. But not sure if it is less than $1$. If it is less than $1$ then indeed $f^3\lt f^2$

Comment: @aarbee See my answer for this.

Comment: If the max rate of growth is $1$ everywhere then $f(x)\leq x$

Comment: @NinadMunshi that's a wonderful line of thinking. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we say $\int_0^1f^2(1)dx>\int_0^1f^3(x)dx$?

Yes, we can.

Note that by MVT,  we have
$$|f(1) - f(0)| = f'(\xi)|1-0| \in (0,1] \implies f(1) \in (0,1] \tag{$\star$}$$
for some $\xi \in (0,1]$. Therefore
$$\int_0^1 f^3(x)dx < f^3(1) \overset{(\star)}\le f^2(1) = \int_0^1 f^2(1) dx$$
as you wish.

Comment: Is the absolutely value necessary at the beginning of your proof ? I think it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity is

$$ Q(f) = \frac{f(1)^2}{\int_0^1 f^3(x)dx}$$

First observation: for each $\alpha \in (0,1)$,

$$Q(\alpha f) = \alpha^{-1} Q(f).$$

Thus the quantity can get as large as we please. So we need to minimize $Q(f)$.

For now assume that $c = f(1)$ is fixed. Since $f(x) \le x$ and $f(x) \le f(1) = c$, we have

$$ f(x) \le \min \{x, c\} = \begin{cases} x & x\in [0,c] \\ c & x\in [c, 1].\end{cases}$$

and thus

$$\int_0^1 f^3(x) dx < \frac{c^4}{4}+ c^3(1-c) = c^3\left( 1- \frac 34 c\right)$$

(we have strictly inequality here, since $f$ is differentiable and $f$ cannot be $\min\{x, c\}$). This implies

$$Q(f) > \frac{1}{c (1-3c/4)}.$$

The function $c\mapsto c(1-3c/4)$ is maximized at $c = 2/3$, thus

$$ Q(f) >3.$$

So it seems that all four options are correct...